# A place to rent a killer whale submarine?

Tags: where-on-earth, submarines, water-sports

Before you close the question, take a look at the [killer whale submarine](http://www.hammacher.com/Product/11990?source=cj&PID=5652142&cm_mmc=CJ-_-3624600-_-5652142-_-Hammacher+Product+Catalog) :).

I would buy one but I do not have $100,000. So is there a place in the world to rent one of those for one hour or so?

[image]

Comment: The Seabreacher has an unbelievably irritating website that keeps reloading whole screen background pictures for as long as you stay on it. If you are paying for your data download ABSOLUTELY DO NOT VISIT THIS SITE. (I guess their visitors are the kind for whom $100,000 is chump change)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to ask the "Killer whale submarine" (aka *Seabreacher*) dealers close to your place / the region where you'd like to rent it.

[This page](http://seabreacher.com/dealers/) lists dealers over the world.

- [Hydro Attack](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hydro-Attack/356252091141128) in Queenstown, NZ, has a ["tour operator" mode](https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.404536889645981.1073741829.356252091141128&type=1) for the Seabreacher; I don't know if you can drive it though.
- [Extremalov](http://www.extremalov.ru/rental/), their Russian dealer in Moscow, rents a few things but no Seabreacher is listed on the website (you may ask nevertheless).
- [Seabreacher Australia](http://seabreacher.com.au/) states in [their FAQ](http://seabreacher.com.au/pages/faq.php):

> Can I rent one? Not at this stage, but many of our customers have
>   expressed interest in starting Seabreacher rental operations, so there
>   may be a Seabreacher rental facility near you in the upcoming future.